# Entity Framework: Add 'appears' to work but data is not saved

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, inversion-of-control

At Business Level I have this save method (in a Manager class):

```
public void Save(Models.My source)
{
    using (var scope = base.GetTransactionScope())
    {
        this.MyRepository.SetContext(scope.Context);

        this.MyRepository.Add(source.ToMy(), scope.Context);

        scope.Commit();
    }
}
```

The set up is done to make sure that everything within the Save Scope is using the same ObjectContext.

This is the code of the `MyRepository.Add` call:

```
public void Add(My source, MyEntities context)
{
    var isNew = (source.ID == Guid.Empty);
    source.ID = Guid.NewGuid();

    base.Add(source, context, isNew, source.EntityState);
}
```

And the `base.Add` call:

```
protected void Add<T>(T source, MyEntities context, bool isNew, EntityState state) where T : class
{
    if (isNew)
    {
        context.CreateObjectSet<T>().AddObject(source);
    }
    else
    {
        if (state == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            context.CreateObjectSet<T>().Attach(source);

            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(source, EntityState.Modified);
        }
    }
}
```

After this the code passes to the `scope.Commit()` of the above save method, which does the Context.SaveChanges():

```
public void Commit()
{
    this.Context.SaveChanges();

    this.Transaction.Complete();
}
```

**The issue**

The update part (the else code in the `base.Add`) works just fine, the insert however, while it 'looks' to be working, does not have any effect.
I mean it looks to be working because the EntityState changes from Detached to Added.

Since everything happens on the same Context, I would think that I'm doing things correctly, so

**The question**

What am I missing that causes my Save to fail, although everything 'appears' to be in order?

Comment: In the `scope.Commit()`. I've added the code.

Comment: In IsNew part try to use context.Set(typeof(T)).Add(source);

Comment: Set is unknown, I'm on EF4. And since I have to keep existing functionality (and other people) in mind, I can't just update the version.